# How to structure ansible roles for multiple application use?

Tags: python, node.js, deployment, ansible

I'm looking for the most modular way to use ansible to provision a server that will host multiple node.js applications on it. The current setup I have is not scalable.

The roles I have are `common`, `nginx`, `nodejs`, `mongodb`, `apps`.

### The `apps` hash/dictionary

I maintain a dict called `apps` in `roles/apps/defaults/main.yml` and this is both the solution and problem:

```
- apps:
    shark:
      repo: git@example.com:shark.git
      subdomain: shark
      port: 3001
    tiger:
      repo: git@example.com:tiger.git
      subdomain: tiger
      port: 3002
```

Example of how the `apps` dict is used in `roles/apps/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: clone repos
  git: repo={{ item.value.repo }}
  with_dict: apps

- name: create vhost
  template:
    src=vhost.j2
    dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ item.value.subdomain }}
  with_dict: apps
  sudo: yes
```

### `playbook.yml`

Both `staging.yml` and `production.yml` playbooks are set to run all of the aforementioned roles. That means that both servers will install **all** of the apps configured in the `apps` dict.

I need to figure out a more modular pattern for `roles/apps` so that I can install different apps on the different environments. Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify which apps go to which machine directly in `staging.yml` and `production.yml`.

Any idea how this can be accomplished? Feel free to suggest entirely different methods of configuring multiple apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to maintain another dict, you could parameterize the `with_dict` to:

```
- name: clone repos
  git: repo={{ item.value.repo }}
  with_dict: {{env_app_dict}}
```

and specify your `env_app_dict` in either the inventory file or via the command line.

edit: Alternatively, try the [lookup plugin](https://github.com/tfishersp/ansible_fileglob_to_dict) that I wrote and specify folders for apps_common, apps_production, and apps_staging.

With this plugin, you'd put a collection of common items in apps_common and:

```
- name: clone common repos
  git: repo="{{item.repo}}"
  fileglob_to_dict:
    - "{{ 'apps_common/*' }}"
```

and then simply specify the apps_env file parameter (as in the original answer) that you want by either targeting with a host pattern (e.g. `- hosts: staging` in the play) or by specifying the parameter on the command line or inventory file.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I figured out was to create dictionaries for the various apps in `roles/apps/defaults/main.yml`:

```
shark:
  repo: git@example.com:shark.git
  subdomain: shark
  port: 3001

tiger:
  repo: git@example.com:tiger.git
  subdomain: tiger
  port: 3002
```

Note the fact that they're not enclosed inside an `apps` dict.

Then, specify the `apps` dict contents in `staging.yml` or `production.yml` instead:

```
- hosts: example
  vars:
    apps:
      - '{{ shark }}'
      - '{{ tiger }}'
```

This allows you to direct which applications are included in which playbook.